# Cannot access list elements outside for loop

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

If someElements is not empty, endList in the last line of code, should equal someElements.
It works ok.

If someElements is empty, endList in the last line of code, should contain elements appended in L6.
In this case endList is always empty.

What is the reason of it?

```
{{ $global := .}}
{{- $endList := $global.Values.someElements -}}
{{- if not $endList }}
  {{- $endList := list }}
  {{- range $nestedElement := $global.Values.nestedstructure.nested1 }}
    {{- $endList = append $endList $nestedElement.Code  }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- $microservice :=  $global.Release.Name | replace "-" "" -}}
{{- range $nestedElement := $global.Values.nestedstructure.nested1 }}
{{if has $nestedElement.Code $endList }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed := to = in L4.
Thanks to this the variable is accessible beyond the loop.

Comment: ...the `:=` creates a new `$endList` variable that's scoped to the containing `if` block.